# Write the component form of the vector given the magnitude $\|v\|=17$ and $\theta=42$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I need to find the component form of a vector with magnitude $\|v\|=17$ and angle $\theta=42^{\circ}$. How do I find $v$? I've tried $17\cos(42)$ but I'm not sure that's correct.

Answer (score 2):

What you've been given is the magnitude and direction of the vector $\left(r,\theta\right)=\left(17,42^{\circ}\right)$. They're asking for the $\left(x,y\right)$ form of this vector.

Remember from trigonometry that $x=r\cos\theta$ and $y=r\sin\theta$. What do you think that your component form $\left(x,y\right)$ would look like when plugging in your values of $r$ and $\theta$?

*Hint:* You've got half of it already.

Answer (score 0):

You need two components, not just one. Draw a right triangle with your vector the hypotenuse. $17 \cos 42$ is one leg-which? What is the other?